# function conflict with html body for hamburger click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so basically I am currently using a script like this that allows me to click on the area where my popout menu isn't open and it will close which is great.....

```
 //ALLOWS CLICK ON THE BODY TO CLOSE THE MENU//
    $( '#colorscreen' ).click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');   
    });
```

colorscreen is a near invisible overlay that has a very low z-index which means other elements interfere with its function....

if i replace colorscreen with body the code simply doesn't work because the menu itself is of course within the body making the use of the body in the function impossible.

is there a way of replacing the div #colorscreen with something that allows me to just click anywhere on the body without confusing the popout menu?....

i was hoping there would be a reverse function that could say something like "if you dont click on the menu then close it" i don't know hence my post.

**EDIT :
This edit includes the suggested not statement which works but doesn't allow the class active to change so that is now what i need to solve with this new statement**

```
$(":not(#menu .navbtn)").click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');   
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)) or `.not()` selectors ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/not/)).

```
$(":not(#menu)").click(function(){
```

Comment: Hi Tims yes that worked but it doesn't seem to reset the navbtn state by removing and adding the active class...almost as if only half the statement works >? document.ready perhaps ?